# request to Random Word SetGetGo API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm trying to get words from this website: http://setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php
How do I create a request to this API? Is there something that i'm missing?

```
function RandomWord() {
var requestStr = "http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: requestStr,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'RandomWordComplete'
});
}

function RandomWordComplete(data) {
     alert(data.Word);
}
```

Comment: What is `new Discord.Client();` ?

Comment: I'm creating a discord bot

Comment: I took out the discord stuff because it's insignificant

Comment: Do you have control over [setgetgo](http://setgetgo.com/randomword/get.php) ?

Comment: No i do not. It's a .php file that has random words that I want to access

Comment: The easier way I think of... Would be to make my own random word ressource. All I get on online code editors is `Mixed Content: The page at [...]  was loaded over HTTPS, but requested [...] an insecure script [...]. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` ... So that already is a problem.

Comment: That's just a word list... You should look at PHP. Use a JS array if you can't do PHP. But the array will be visible in page code... Which may not be important.

Comment: API isn't working anymore.